# Unescaped form input value in Thymeleaf template (something similar to utext)

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I know you can show unescaped text by using utext as described here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text

But if I want to display unescaped value of a form input, using data-th-value="${model.value}", there is no equivalent data-th-uvalue.

I wonder if there is a way to do this in thymeleaf?  If not, what is the best workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had your same doubt, this is what I did to achieve that

```
<input type="hidden" id="responseObj" th:value="${#strings.unescapeJava(responseObj)}" />
```

it was the only way I found.

I hope it was what you asked about.